# Sorting values and percentages creating inaccuracies

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to return the percentage change of value B using the value of B-1. However I when I run the for loop I am using to carry out this calculation I get 100% from A- B (the first two values).
Here is the table in reference to give you more context

```
val     pct_of_whole
3612       100.0
2339        65.0
2339        65.0
2208        61.0
1890        52.0
1368        38.0
1365        38.0
1363        38.0
1086        30.0      
1058        29.0
```

So from this table I am trying to return the percentage change from 3612 to 2339, from 2339 to 2339, from 2208 to 2339 etc.

This is the for loop I am using to carry out the percentage change calculation:

```
  pct_change=[100]
  length = len(df_two['val'])
  for j in range(1,length):
        pct_change.append(int(df_two['val'][j]/df_two['val'][j-1]*100))
```

At this point this point my chart retains the correct percentage changes. Since I am building a funnel showing drop-offs between each stage I sort the values from smallest to largest

```
  df_two = df_two.sort_values('val').reset_index(drop=True)
```

At this point the percentage changes start looking inaccurate

```
val        pct_of_whole      pct_change     
1058           29.0              97
1086           30.0              79
1363           38.0              99
1365           38.0              99
1368           38.0              99
1890           52.0              72
2208           61.0              94
2339           65.0              64
2339           65.0              100
3612           100.0             100
```

Understandably this makes the funnel i build appear inaccurate.
I think when I sort by val the 2339 with the higher percentage change is incorrectly placed as the second in order- which is the cause of my confusion

Comment: This looks like Pandas to me so I added the appropriate tag, please edit the tags if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry - now I understand the question... :)

To sort for different columns in a different direction (i.e. one column ascending, the other descending), you can provide lists for both kwargs, `by` and `ascending`:

```
df.sort_values(['val', 'pct_change'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)

    val  pct_of_whole  pct_change
0  1058     29.291251   97.421731
1  1086     30.066445   79.677183
2  1363     37.735327   99.853480
3  1365     37.790698   99.780702
4  1368     37.873754   72.380952
5  1890     52.325581   85.597826
6  2208     61.129568   94.399316
7  2339     64.756368  100.000000
8  2339     64.756368   64.756368
9  3612    100.000000         NaN
```

---

IIUC, your dataframe can be done like this:

Given a dataframe with column `val`

```
df

0    3612
1    2339
2    2339
3    2208
4    1890
5    1368
6    1365
7    1363
8    1086
9    1058
```

the `pct_of_whole` can be calculated via

```
df.val/df.val.loc[0]*100

0    100.000000
1     64.756368
2     64.756368
3     61.129568
4     52.325581
5     37.873754
6     37.790698
7     37.735327
8     30.066445
9     29.291251
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

...and the `pct_change` would be

```
df.val/df.val.shift()*100

0           NaN
1     64.756368
2    100.000000
3     94.399316
4     85.597826
5     72.380952
6     99.780702
7     99.853480
8     79.677183
9     97.421731
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that after running the for loop the dataframe was in the inverse of the order I wanted.

So i reset the index to give each of the values an index number from 0-9.

```
  df_two = df_two.reset_index()
```

I then sorted the order of my dataframe by the index and reset the index again - dropping this index.

```
df_two = df_two.sort_values('index',ascending =False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

After this both my dataframe and funnel were in the right order